# Combinatorics - Forbidden selection

Tags: combinatorics

John and Lily are getting married. The extended family wants to have their picture taken, but John's father is unwilling to stand next to Lily's mother. How many options does the photographer have to arrange the 10 family members in a row for the picture?

How do I tackle this question?

Total no of ways to arrange 10 person in a row is = 10! = 3,628,800

There are 4 forbidden positions where:

John's father taking 1st position and Lily's mother taking 2nd position, and vice versa (2 combinations).

John's father taking 10th position and Lily's mother taking the 9th position, and vice versa (2 combinations).

How do I write my formula to account for the rest of the positions between 2nd and 8th, where Lily's Mother can either stand left or right beside David's father?

i.e. John's father is at the fifth position. Lily's mother can either take up the 4th or 6th position. _ _ _ _ John's Father _ _ _ _ _

Comment: I wonder why I am receiving downvote for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose Father and Mother as 1 person. You have $8!$ posibilities to arrange the other menbers. Then you have 9 positions to put the father and Mother, but you can insert in two ways (father-mother or mother-father). Then the forbidden arrangements are $2\cdot 9\cdot 8!\,$ and the valid arrangements are the rest $10!- 2\cdot9\cdot8!=90\cdot8!-18\cdot8!=72\cdot8!$

Comment: Why do we take both parents as 1 person?

Comment: @ilovetolearn Perhaps it would be better to say as one unit.  We are subtracting the number of cases in which John's father and Lily's mother are standing together from the total number of arrangements.  If they are standing together, we can treat them as a unit.  Then we have nine objects to arrange, the unit containing John's father and Lily's mother and the other eight persons.  The objects can be arranged in $9!$ ways.  Within the unit, John's father and Lily's mother can be arranged in $2!$ ways.  Hence, there are $2 \cdot 9!$ impermissible arrangements.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Great explanation! I finally got it.